# How can I get the intended URL in a 404?

Tags: customization, urls, 404-error

I am customizing a `404` page, and I would like to know the correct way to get the intended URL within `404.php`.

Do I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as some online resources seem to suggest, or is there a WordPress builtin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is  your only option. wordpress failed parsing the url so not much you can get from the API

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect specific `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to `yoursite.com/not_found`